# Build a dictionary based on split string

Tags: python, beginner, strings, python-2.x, hash-map

I've written a simple script that takes a string filled with brackets and strings and builds them to a dictionary.

Example Input:

```
string_1 = '(()())'
string_2 = '((a)(b))'
string_3 = '(a(a)b(b)c)'
string_4 = 'a(a(a)b(b)c)b'
string_4 = 'a[a{a}b{b}c]b'
string_5 = 'beginning(content[word]{another word})outside'
```

Output for `string5` [and the other examples](http://pastebin.com/vG2FfRiQ):

```
[
('0-8', 'beginning'),
('9', '('),
('10-16', 'content'),
('17', '['),
('18-21', 'word'),
('22', ']'),
('23', '{'),
('24-35', 'another word'),
('36', '}'),
('37', ')'),
('38-44', 'outside')
]
```

---

```
def sort(dictionary):
    return sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda v: int(v[0].split("-")[0]))


def join(a, b):
    return ''.join([repr(a), '-', repr(b - 1)]) if a != b else repr(b)


class Positions:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.content = {}  # creates a new empty list for each bracket

    def push(self, pos, content):
        self.content[pos] = content


def convert_string(string):
    string_content = string
    string = Positions(string)
    pos = 0
    start_of_str_pos = 0
    internal_string = ''
    for char in string_content:
        if char in ['(', '{', '[', ')', '<', '}', ']', '>']:
            string.push(repr(pos), repr(char))
            if internal_string != '':
                string.push(join(start_of_str_pos, pos), internal_string)
                internal_string = ''
            start_of_str_pos = pos + 1
        else:
            internal_string += char
        pos += 1

    if internal_string != '':
        string.push(''.join([repr(start_of_str_pos),
                             '-', repr(pos - 1)]), internal_string)
    print sort(string.content)
```

Comment: Is this a simple implementation of my parentheses matching idea? It looks a little like it...

Comment: 1. Why is the output on Pastebin? 2. PEP-8 recommends `lowercase_with_underscore` function/variable names, so you're not yet fully compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Obvious but easy

There are some issues that are immediately obvious and easy to correct.

---

In this statement:

> ```
> return ''.join([repr(a), '-', repr(b - 1)]) if a != b else repr(b)
> ```

The multiple `repr` are awkward,
and so is the `join`.
It would be less awkward, simpler and more readable by using string formatting:

```
return '{}-{}'.format(a, b - 1) if a != b else repr(a)
```

---

This can be written a lot simpler:

> ```
> if char in ['(', '{', '[', ')', '<', '}', ']', '>']:
> ```

Like this:

```
if char in '({[)<}]>':
```

But actually, it's a bit disturbing that the opening and closing brackets are ordered inconsistently. For example, looking at this string, it's not immediately obvious that it includes all matching closing brackets for all opening brackets. This way would be immediately obvious and less error prone:

```
if char in '(){}[]<>':
```

---

This is both confusing and disturbing:

> ```
> def convert_string(string):
>     string_content = string
>     string = Positions(string)
> ```

Why shuffle around the `string` parameter?
It's a bad practice to reassign the value of a parameter,
as it makes it confusing what it really stands for throughout the function.

Another problem here is calling an instance of `Positions` a "string".
Later in the code when I read "string",
I think it's an actually string, but in fact it's not,
it's an instance of "Positions".
Very misleading.

---

Since empty strings are *falsy*, instead of this:

> ```
> if internal_string != '':
>     # ...
> ```

You can write simply:

```
if internal_string:
    # ...
```

#### Obvious but harder

There are some issues that are sort of obviously wrong,
but not so easy to correct.

---

This sorting function smells:

```
def sort(dictionary):
    return sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda v: int(v[0].split("-")[0]))
```

Instead of splitting a string and parsing to int,
my instinct says there should be a way to use the original int values directly.

In general, the code formats these strings from int values,
and it seems silly to later un-format the strings so you can sort.
There should be a better way.

---

The `Positions` class stinks.
It's called "Positions",
but its fields are "name" and "content".
Sounds more like a key-value pair.

Then there's this code with the comment:

> ```
>    self.content = {}  # creates a new empty list for each bracket
> ```

The comment talks about "list", but the code uses a dictionary.

And there's the `push` method:

> ```
> def push(self, pos, content):
>     self.content[pos] = content
> ```

`push` is a term commonly used with stacks, or sometimes with lists.
But here the method puts a value into a dictionary,
an operation normally called "put".

#### Alternative implementation

Based on the above suggestions,
and reorganizing to more meaningful elements,
you could do something like this:

```
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Item:
    def __init__(self, start, end, content):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.content = content

    @property
    def position(self):
        a = self.start
        b = self.end
        return '{}-{}'.format(a, b - 1) if a != b else repr(a)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.start < other.start


def convert_string(string):
    start = 0
    internal_string = ''
    items = []
    for (pos, char) in enumerate(string):
        if char in '(){}[]<>':
            items.append(Item(pos, pos, char))
            if internal_string:
                items.append(Item(start, pos, internal_string))
                internal_string = ''
            start = pos + 1
        else:
            internal_string += char

    if internal_string:
        items.append(Item(start, len(string), internal_string))

    return items
```

Although with the implementation of `__lt__`,
I made it possible to sort simply by `sorted(items)`,
actually there is no need to sort,
as the items are naturally sorted.

Note: the purpose of `@total_ordering` is to implement the other rich comparison operators like `__le__`, as recommended by [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 4):

Just looking at the first few lines of `convert_string()`…

> ```
> def convert_string(string):
>     string_content = string
>     string = Positions(string)
>     pos = 0
>     start_of_str_pos = 0
>     …
> ```

… and the last line…

> ```
>     …
>     print sort(string.content)
> ```

… I'm pretty confused!  Why are you renaming the `string` parameter to `string_content`?  Then why is `string` not a string, but a `Positions` object?  And that object's *name* is actually the string, whereas its *content* is a dictionary?  On top of that, `string_content` looks confusingly like `string.content`, but it's actually the same as `string.name`???

Honestly, I'd rather rewrite it from scratch than try to figure out what you did.  I'd use regular expressions, because they are a handy way to do string matching and the right tool for the job.  Instead of printing the results in `convert_string()`, it would be better to return a data structure.  And the data structure I would choose is [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), because it preserves the order in which the keys were added, so you don't have to sort the result.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

def convert_string(s):
    result = OrderedDict()
    for match in re.finditer(r'[^<({\[\]})>]+|(?P<delim>.)', s):
        if match.group('delim'):
            result[str(match.start())] = match.group()
        else:
            result['%d-%d' % (match.start(), match.end() - 1)] = match.group()
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an odd mix of class and function. Rather than a standalone function that creates a `Positions` object from a string, for example, I would make that a class method:

```
class Positions(object):  # note new-style class

    CHARS = set('()[]{}<>')  # class attribute, uses set to speed up 'in'

    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        ...
```

Now rather than calling `convert_string(foo)`, you can get a `Positions` instance with `Positions.from_string(foo)`. Similarly, you could move the `join` and `sort` functionality into the class, as they're all connected to each other. You should move the *"pretty print"* formatting into a `__str__` method.

---

Your sort function has a problem; it only works for the first "level". Rather than encapsulate the whole sort in a function, I would write a custom sort `key` function, then replace e.g.

```
print sort(string.content)
```

with:

```
print sorted(string.content, key=sort_key)
```

For example, you could use `map` to apply `int` to all of the parts of the key:

```
def sort_key(item):
    """Convert string for multi-level numerical sort.

        >>> sort_key(('1-2-3', None))
        [1, 2, 3]

    """
    key, _ = item
    return map(int, key.split('-'))
```

Or, alternatively, use a tuple of integers (`(1, 2, 3)`, in this case) as the key rather than a string.

Note the [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to explain what the function does and provide built-in demonstration/testing with [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html). A docstring would be particularly useful in `join`, which does some odd things I couldn't quite figure out and would really benefit from explanation. As it stands, your script only has a single explanatory comment:

```
self.content = {}  # creates a new empty list for each bracket
```

which isn't actually true!